# google api javascript client Drive Api and access to Spreadsheets

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

if Google Drive API will be supported by access to Spreadsheet API

Or it's will be new Spreadsheet API like we have

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Similar to developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/

Answer (score 2):

[Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) allows you to do CRUD (create,read, update,delete) functions to google drive. This is similar to the Google Documents List API for Google Docs and is the latest evolution.  To actually edit or retrieve the contents inside a spreadsheet you must still use the Spreadsheet api which you listed above.  The latest versions of the spreadsheet api also use Oath2 just like the Drive api.